# Regex multiple lines and capture specific text between

Tags: regex

I have the following string (that changes except the first row, thats my starting point):

```
Action 0100: Register: 
2021.01.05 14:38:08 CET 
REF: 12345678910
FAK: Street,ZIP

===========================
```

I want to capture everything between the date row until the row with the equal signs.

```
REF: 12345678910
FAK: Street,ZIP
```

I tried something like this at first when i only had one row, but when i have both REF and FAK rows, i need something better:

```
(?:.+Register.+\n.+\n)(.+)
```

I would like to have everything captured into one group. Because i need to verify if there is any other rows then REF or FAK

Comment: What about `Register:\s*\n\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} .*\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8sOTUS/1). Or less precise `Register.*\n.*\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8sOTUS/2))?

Comment: Register.*\n.*\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)
Looks great, but somehow when i'm using this within my environment i'm still getting the row "===========================" and the text after that. Is there someway to use the above expressions with a positive lookahead?

Comment: What is the place where you use the regex? Try `(?-s:Register.*\n.*\n(.+(?:\n.+)*))`

Comment: Well it works at https://regex101.com/. But i'm using an application that uses Visual Basic in the background for regex, and it does seem to getting the row "===========================" and the text after that.

Comment: Visual Basic for Application (like in Excel) or VB.NET? What are the options exposed to you? Do you have access to code? Also, try `Register(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n){2}([^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*)`

Comment: Did it work????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Register(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n){2}([^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*)
```

*Details*:

- `Register` - a fixed string
- `(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n){2}` - two sequences of zero or more chars other than CR and LF and then an optional CR followed with one LF char
- `([^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\r\n]+` - one or more chars other than CRLF
  - `(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of CLRF or LF line ending sequence and then one or more chars other than CR and LF.